# Any listener for microphone(mic) in android

Tags: android, microphone

I have developed a app in which i have developed audio focus change listener successfully. i want same listener like audio focus change listener for mic. So i can control the mic activity    .Is there any listener for mic in android or if not so how can i control the mic like audio(speaker).

Comment: Could you please explain the term "audio focus"?